# Deployment problem in ojdbc6 in Jboss Redhat EAP with ojdbc14 based war file?

Tags: java, oracle, jboss, redhat

I have a problem in running my war file that is ojdbc14 based (which uses classes) and I need to deploy it together in my JBoss EAP Server which has ojdbc6 (there are applications in the server which uses ojdbc6 so I cant replace it)

I tried putting them together in the /com/oracle/jdbc/main but unable to start the server.

I also tried the jboss-deployment-structure.xml and I'm not sure if i'm doing it right.

here is the snippet of the deployment structure if it helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<jboss-deployment-structure>  
        <dependencies>
             <module name="com.oracle.jdbc.ojdbc14" slot="main" />   
        </dependencies>
      <sub-deployment name="Project.war">  
            <dependencies>  
                <system>  
                    <paths>  
                        <path name="com/oracle/jdbc/"/>  
                    </paths>  
                </system>  
            </dependencies>  

          </sub-deployment>  
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Any inputs would be appreciated thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two modules in JBoss EAP server. One module for ojdbc6 and other for ojdbc14.

> Module.xml for ojdbc6

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="oracle.jdbc" slot="6">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

> Module.xml for ojdbc14

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="oracle.jdbc" slot="14">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="ojdbc14.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Import above dependency in your application according to your requirements.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
              ....
              <module name="oracle.jdbc" slot="slot_of_required_jar"/>
              ....
        </dependencies>
    ....
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Thank you Abhijeet ! Will definitely try this. Currently I am placing my jboss-deployment-structure in my WEB-INF in my project. That is the correct path for it isn't it? Btw regarding the separate modules, can they be in same path or must be in different?

Comment: Modules can be on same path but slot should be different. Means path will be like modules/com/oracle/jdbc/v14/ojdb14.jar and modules/com/oracle/jdbc/v6/ojdb6.jar. Here v6 and v14 are your slots

Comment: I have JBoss 7.2 EAP and have placed ojdbc module `$JBOSS_HOME/oracle/jdbc/main` where `main` is my slot

Comment: @Starvinmarvinnn jboss-deployment-structure should be in WEB-INF folder

Comment: Thanks will get back to you as soon as I try it. Btw I removed the ojdbc14.jar in my WEB-INF/lib path. And will I add an external folder for the odjbc14.jar in my workspace? If I remove it I'm getting tons of error.

Comment: To remove compile time error add ojdbc14 jar at compile time for your project. To analyze the issue share your updated module.xml file and location of your module

Comment: This is the module.xml in the Jboss EAP the path is JBOSS/modules/com/oracle/jdbc/14     ```<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.oracle.jdbc" slot="14">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="ojdbc14.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>```

Comment: 'Add at compile time' you mean adding the jar in Java Build Path right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193623/discussion-between-abhijeet-and-starvinmarvinnn).

Comment: @Starvinmarvinnn Share four things 1. Error you are getting 2. jboss-deployment structure 3. module.xml for ojdbc 4. path to mdodule. Add these details in your question

Comment: I chatted you sir @Abhijeet  Thank you